Can we find $e$ such that $d(e,E) = 1$ and $\|e\|=1$ in a normed space
If $V$ is a normed space, $\mathrm{dim}V=n$ and $E$ is a subspace of $V$ with dimension $n-1$, can we always find an $e \in V$ such that $d(e,E) = 1$ and $\|e\|=1$?
If inner product can be defined in $V$, then this is true, just let $e$ be orthogonal to $E$. But I don't know how to do if there doesn't exist inner product in $V$.
Many thanks in advance!
An edit: I added the condition that $\mathrm{dim}V < \infty$.

You have to assume that $E$ contains the zero vector (a vector hyperplane according to this Wikipedia article). Otherwise it's false, obviously.

Oh yes, sorry I forgot to add this condition. Is it right now? @TonyK

In $\mathbb R^2$ with Euclidean distance and hyperplan of equation $y=x$, the vector
$e=\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$ is an example. Not difficult to show another in finite dimension. In infinite dimension it seems to be possible also.

I was thinking that there could be a counterexample in an infinite-dimenisonal space that is not complete.

French defininition of hyperplan is a subspace so always contains the zero vector. (when it is not so we have an affine hyperplan

@GEdgar: By the way if the hyperplan corresponds to a non continuous linear form, then the hyperplan must be dense so.....(¿?) . This has not to do with completeness an if the linear form is continuous, I think no problem....

It is not true for infinite-dimensional normed spaces, or even inner product spaces. For example, let $V$ be the vector space of finite sequences of reals, with norm $|\textbf{a}|=\sqrt{\sum a_i^2}$ (and similar inner product), and let $E={\textbf{a};|;\sum 2^{-i}a_i=0}$. Then every point is at a distance $0$ from $E$. (I could expand on this in an answer, but then some prowling moderator would demote it to a comment because it doesn't answer your question. But if you changed your question so that it also asked about the infinite-dimensional case, I could post an answer to it!)

For my previous comment to make sense, I have to change the criterion for $E$: it can't have dimension $n-1$, so we make it a subspace with co-dimension $1$ (which comes to the same thing in the finite-dimensional case).

...and now I realise that I should have written $E={\textbf{a};|;\sum 2^ia_i=0}$. ($E={\textbf{a};|;\sum ia_i=0}$ would also work.)
